# In Bash, how to print to stdout when it’s already redirected?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I am writing a Bash function, say `func() { … }`, that interactively asks user a few questions and then runs a certain command.

The prize here is the `stdout` of said command, and I expect users to call my function like this: `func >outfile`, to capture the command’s output in a file.

My question is, how do I print those interactive questions to `stdout` without polluting the useful output?

In other words: within a function, if `stdout` has been potentially redirected by the caller, how do I write to the ‘original’ `stdout` (the terminal), temporarily ignoring caller’s redirect?

Do I have to resort to using `stderr` for output that semantically doesn’t belong there?

Comment: Do you know how to *copy* file descriptors, and thus make a backup?

Comment: That said, prompts **are** semantically supposed to go to stderr. It's not just for "errors" as such, it's also for "diagnostics" and other content that isn't output proper. You'll notice that bash itself prints the shell prompt, and `read -p '...'` prompts, to stderr.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I’m talking about a scenario, where redirect is made *before* I have a chance to save original stdout.

Comment: ...if you really want to write to the *terminal* as such, that's what `/dev/tty` is for. But again, prompts belong on stderr.

Comment: That said, why can't the same code that defines your function also define a backup of stdout? `exec {orig_stdout}>&1` at definition time and there you are, your function can write things `>"$orig_stdout"` when called. (Note that the above is functionality available in bash 4.1 and later).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You make an interesting point about stderr. May be I should just go with it. Somehow, `/dev/tty` seems ‘wronger.’ Thank you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I feel like I maybe misunderstand you. Wouldn’t line `{orig_stdout}>&1` be executed *after* the caller has replaced the `orig_stdout`?

Comment: I've tried to expand into an answer rather than just leaving a comment -- hopefully the format allows more clarity?

Comment: (BTW, I agree that `/dev/tty` is a hack, although occasionally a necessary one -- after all, there *isn't* always a TTY, and if there isn't, opening it will simply fail; it's more likely that there *will* always be a usable stderr, and if there isn't, that tends to clearly be the fault of whatever failed to provide one in the calling environment).

Comment: I think that failing is a good thing if you are prompting the user for input.  Thus, while hackish, I think /dev/tty is a reasonable way of approaching this.  Alternatively, when taking the stderr approach ( preferred ) , you can first check to make sure stderr is a terminal ( [ -t 1 ] ).  If the test fails, your end user will not see your prompt - so it's better to provide a default value or provide a useful error message.

Comment: @Mark I assume, you mean, `[ -t 2 ]`, but thanks for the useful input.

Comment: @CBlew - you assumed correctly - I'm glad you caught it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answering The Original Question

Create a backup of your original stdout at the point in time when your function is defined, and you can use it at invocation time.

```
exec {myfunc_stdout_fd}>&1
myfunc() {
  echo "Content sent to stdout as defined at invocation time"
  echo "Content sent to original stdout" >&"$myfunc_stdout_fd";
}
```

...whereafter:

```
myfunc_out=$(myfunc)
```

...stores `Content sent to stdout as defined at invocation time` in `myfunc_out`, and immediately writes `Content sent to original stdout` to the stdout that was defined when the function definition took place.

See this running in an online interpreter at https://ideone.com/HwHRJ7

---

#### Advice Re: Best-Practice Usage

Prompts are conventionally written to stderr on UNIX, so for prompting-related purposes, retaining the original stdout isn't generally called for. Prompting on stderr is what `read -p` does; what bash itself does (like other shells); etc. This is appropriate, as POSIX defines stderr as the appropriate stream for "diagnostic output", which is a category that includes status about what the program is doing at the moment (whether it's ready for more input, f/e).

See also:

- [How to display a custom prompt during the execution of C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820420/how-to-display-a-custom-prompt-during-the-execution-of-c-program)
- [What are the conventions for stdout/stderr messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977852/what-are-the-conventions-for-stdout-stderr-messages)

Comment: Oh, right! You are suggesting capturing stdout at the time when the function definition is sourced, in hopes that sourcing itself is done in unmodified IO environment. Neat idea, my compliments. That being said, you make a convincing case for stderr. Thank you for your time.